# Why should I use ActionbarSherlock?

Tags: android, user-interface, actionbarsherlock, native, android-support-library

I have seen tons of answers related to usage of ActionbarSherlock. Even that I use it for months I still don't have an answer why should I really used? What more it gives than the regular Android support library? I can use the support lib to gain the same visual appearance.
I know it uses either the support or the native implementation depending on the running android version, but what's the practical benefit of this?

Comment: My mistake. Go, kill me with downvotes!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What more it gives than the regular Android support library? I can use
>   the support lib to gain the same visual appearance.

There is **no** support ActionBar in the support lib. ABS is the only backport of the ActionBar. So if you want to have an ActionBar on ore HC devices, then this is the only way how to.

**Edit:** 
 
There's now an official back port of the `ActionBar` available in the support library.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. No actionbar in Support lib! I was confused because of the name of method getSupportActionBar() which is introduced in ABS NOT in the Support lib!

Answer (score 3):

`ActionBarSherlock` basically provides BACKWARD COMPATIBILITY which the android support library -v4 doesn't. It is because of this library and `HoloEveryWhere` that users can enjoy ICS-like UI on their old phones (froyo,gingerbread,etc). If you are targetting Honeycomb/ICS/JB , just use native ActionBar. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

It works on older platforms.  Like Android 2.0.