# Android Sherlock VS AppCompat

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-appcompat

i want to my application could run in all of android version and after any research about it i'm find to component about that such as `Sherlock` and `AppCompat` whats difference `Sherlock` and `AppCompat`? which is best for my application to work all of android version such as `Fragment` , `Actionbar` or etc?

`Sherlock` is Hard to import and use that in Eclipse and Intllij and i can not work simply that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@TuxWorld, Action bar is a component that adds a bar on top of your application.

Android provides a native implementation as part of SDK which is the "AppCompat" version you are referring to. "Sherlock" is an extension to the native implementation (Before there was a native implementation, Sherlock was the way to add action bar). Sherlock version is an open source library that you will have to add to your project where as SDK is already available for you. For most cases using Actionbar provided by AppCompat would fine. However depends on what you are really trying to achieve.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks. you say `"AppCompat" AND "Sherlock" is an native implementation`? i don't underestand. which is best? can `AppCompat` support all version of android such as fragment, actionbar,theme design? need to use `Sherlock` inside `AppCompat` ?

Comment: Appcompat is built in control. It comes as part of android SDK. Sherlock is a library. Back in the day Google did not have a actionbar so many used sherlock. Now Google put action bar as part of SDK.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15072741/710802

Comment: then all of any feature in `Sherlock` supported with `Appcompat` and it does not required. is this true?